# Not able to set an option to select tag with spaces using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery. I've a label called "Market News", where I need to make this option value as selected to the existing select tag which has other options too. But, it throws me an error

```
var label = "Market News";
```

### Code

```
$('#labels option[value='+label+']').attr('selected','selected');
```

### Error

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #labels option[value=Market News]
```

How can I overcome this issue? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You need to simply use `.val()`

```
$('#labels').val(label);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes and the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$('#labels option[value="'+label+'"]').prop('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes to attribute selector value:

```
$('#labels option[value="'+label+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
                        ^         ^
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to search by text content of option, not value you need to use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$('#labels option:contains("'+label+'")').attr('selected','selected');
```

Comment: @ashrafi.iqbal Is `Market Value` really the `value` of the option, or is it the text after the option?